# What is "GFI WebMonitor Secure Download"? and how to disable it?

Tags: webserver

Please help me to disable it! it offends me while downloading via Web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[GFI WebMonitor](http://www.gfi.com/internet-monitoring-software/webmonnew.htm) is a software for "Web Security, Monitoring & Internet Access Control".
Most likely it's installed by the person who is responsible for your internet connection. so you need to talk to her/him

Comment: "M$ gold certified"? "[buzzword] Monitoring & Internet Access Control"? Sounds like spyware / crapware to me :D

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a Download Control Policy

To disable a download control policy:

1. Click on **WebSecurity Edition → Download Control Policies** from the navigation pane.
2. Uncheck the checkbox in the **Enabled** column for the policy you want to disable.
3. Complete disabling a download policy by clicking on **Save Settings**.

**NOTE**: Failing to click on Save Settings means that you will lose settings as soon as you leave the view to move to another section in GFI WebMonitor.